# Is there a way to ask tox to run environments matching a name or by group?

Tags: python, tox

I have a `tox.ini` with several envs, like this example:

```
[tox]
envlist =
    py37,
    py38,
    py39,
    lint-{foo,bar,baz}
...
```

For several of my users, only a subset of these is useful at a time, usually all the `py3` ones *or* all the `lint-` ones.

Is there a syntax such that instead of `tox -e py37,py38,py39`, one can say "run all envs (a subset of what tox finds via `tox -a`) matching `py3`"?

Alternatively, is there a way to group the envs so that one can say "run the `test` envs" or "run the `cleanup` envs" without losing the ability to call `tox` to run them all?

I can write a separate script to handle this, but I'm searching for a built-in way to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest to a built-in way to filter tox environments by name is the `TOX_SKIP_ENV` environment variable, which tox uses as a pattern for [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) (see [source](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/blob/a7903508fa07068b327e15cfdbf8ea330ab78765/src/tox/session/__init__.py#L145)) with each environment name, skipping those that match.

So, for example, to only run the `lint-` prefixed environments, one could:

```sh
env TOX_SKIP_ENV='^(?!lint-)' tox
```

Or, to skip all envs with `py` or `bar` anywhere in the name...

```sh
env TOX_SKIP_ENV='.*?(py|bar)' tox
```

There *is* a ([currently unmaintained](https://github.com/pycontribs/tox-tags/issues/5)) tox plugin, [tox-tags](https://github.com/pycontribs/tox-tags/), aiming to provide roughly the tagging/grouping functionality I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

> Alternatively, is there a way to group the envs so that one can say "run the test envs" or "run the cleanup envs" without losing the ability to call tox to run them all?

You can use labels for this. For example, the following in `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
labels =
     test = py310, py39
     static = flake8, mypy
```

allows you to run both `flake8` and `mypy` environments with `tox run -m static`.

Alternatively, you can specify labels in `[testenv:...]` sections, e.g.:

```
[testenv:mypy]
labels = static
commands = mypy src/
...

[testenv:flake8]
labels = static
commands = flake8 src/
...
```

would also result in `tox run -m static` to run both `mypy` and `flake8` environments.

Comment: maybe add some links to the docs: https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#labels and https://tox.wiki/en/latest/cli_interface.html#tox-run-select-target-environment(s)

Comment: Oh nice, seems they added this in Jan 2023 with v4